# SSIS Excel export changes # to

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, ssis-2012

I am exporting an excel file through SSIS using excel connection manager. I am using SSIS 2008 version and the excel is .xlsx

```
CREATE TABLE `Sheet1` (
    `Date` DATETIME,
    `NMMO` NVARCHAR(30),
    `P1 #` NVARCHAR(30),
    `P2 #` NVARCHAR(30)
)
```

but when i see the excel sheet, it gets created but the # symbol is replaced by . I have used `P1 '#` but it does not make any difference. Is there any way i can retain the column names in excel as it is? Please Help

Comment: Do you have to create the sheets in SSIS? I've done it where I make a 'template' of the Excel file I want, and then SSIS makes a copy of that file, and dumps the data into a blank tab that is hidden. The primary tab, 'Sheet1' in your case, would be =A1, =B1, etc. Essentially replicating the results to Sheet1 from the sheet where the results were dumped. This allows me to keep formatting, formulas, graphs, etc.

Comment: I have to create the sheet on runtime and when the package runs, cannot use copy option. as we dont have other location

Comment: You can't create a subfolder in your current location called `Template`, store the template Excel doc there, and copy the template file to the main folder in the SSIS package?

Comment: Can we use a script task to rename a column in excel sheet after the file is created. there is a datetime stamp in excel sheet created.

Comment: @aman6496 have you tried my suggestion, i provided a script task code that can achieve this!!

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the table header using a script task:

*Note: you have to add `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` file to the following directories (.Net Framework dll directory)  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` and (sql server data tools dll directory) `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn` (using vs 2005 and sql 2008) and then add this dll as a reference in your script task*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public void Main()  
    {  

        string filename = @"F:\ExcelLibrary\myexcel.xls";
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            File.Delete(filename);
        }
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application oApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oBook;
        oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Add();
        oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Date";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "NMMO";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "P1 #";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "P2 #";
        //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRange = oSheet.Range["A1", "B3"];
        if (oApp.Application.Sheets.Count < 1)
        {
            oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.Add();
        }
        else
        {
            oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)oApp.Worksheets[1];
        }
        oBook.SaveAs(filename);
        oBook.Close();
        oApp.Quit();
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Don't forget to set the Delay Validation property to `True` for DataFlow Task which contains the Excel Source.

**References**

- [Create Excel File with Header Name by using C# Coding](http://www.dotnetprogramer.in/2015/09/how-to-add-header-names-in-excel-file-through-csharp-coding.html)